# How do I load a separate CSS style sheet a few seconds after when the page loads?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, squarespace

I'm using Squarespace and I am using a plugin/shortcode to prompt people to sign up for a newsletter.
There is certain styling I want applied to the prompt however, Squarespace seems to load the CSS before the plugin runs.
How do I make a certain .css file run say 6 seconds after the page loads so the changes may be applied after the plugin loads  (3-4 seconds after page load).

Comment: I would probably not recommend doing this. Which "plugin" are you using? I've distributed quite a few regarding Squarespace and most of mine rely on using CSS already added into the site via Squarespace's Custom CSS so it gets processed/minified via Squarespace's LESS compiler. Delayed styling and animation is done by applying a CSS class. If you want to clarify your question I can help with a solid solution for this so you're not putting unnecessary requests into your site.

Comment: @jasonbarone yes please. It's the [Privy tool](https://privy.com/)


This is what they have provided.

<!-- BEGIN PRIVY WIDGET CODE -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var _d_site = _d_site || '893F9C65A78C4BF4EA6DAF96';
(function(w, d, p, s, s2) {
  w[p] = w[p] || function() { (w[p].q = w[p].q || []).push(arguments) };
  s = d.createElement('script'); s.async = 1; s.src = '//widget.privy.com/assets/widget.js';
  s2 = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s2.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s2);
})(window, document, 'Privy');
</script>
<!-- END PRIVY WIDGET CODE -->

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript (with Jquery):

```
$(window).load(function(){
   var t=setTimeout(function(){
   $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />');
   },6000);
})
```